# Where is the map stored at different times?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Things I think I understand but please check me:

The map_server is responds to client requests with information about the map. It can respond as a service or it also publishes the same information as a topic. When launched a file on disk can be supplied which will be the initial state of the map that is served up

- How often does it publish as a topic, it would seem that maps can be big and that would be expensive!
- Where is that map stored inside of the map server? In memory, in which case is it lost if/when the map server dies?
- How is the map server told to update the map if ever?
- Does map server ever update the file on disk?
- What if another node updates the file on disk?

[Truth that I have read many of the docs as well as book sections and still am a little fuzzy.]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300492/where-is-the-map-stored-at-different-times?/) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2018-08-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I consider you have already checked the [wiki about map_server](http://wiki.ros.org/map_server).

The map_server simply allows you to read a map or create a new one.

To answer your questions :

- It publishes only one time the map you ask him to. You can check by yourself using `rosrun map_server map_server your_map.yaml`, you will see that the `map_server` reads the informations of the map and publishes on the topics `/map` and `/map_metadata` only one time.
- The map isn't stored by the `map_server`, it reads a map file. You can store a map when creating one (with `gmapping` for example) you can save it to `yaml` and a `pgm` files using `map_saver`. In this case, instead of publishing on the `/map` topic it subscribes to it. But if you don't use `map_saver`, nothing will be stored.
- The map isn't updated. You create one when using `map_saver` but it will only listen to the topic `/map` once to generate the map files and then the node ends itself.
- Cf previous answer : Yes, if you run `rosrun map_serer map_saver` multiple times.
- Unless you directly change the `pgm` file the map isn't updated.

Hope i've answered to all your questions.

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2018-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2018-08-16**:
Thanks for a great answer!! One follow up: SLAM means Simultaneous Localization & Mapping. I assume that means that while we are navigating (using a map) the map can be further improved and extended. If the map on disk is never modified (except when you do map server save) how does this work?

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-08-16**:
Well SLAM is the generic term, you have different types : Hector which relies only on the lidar infirmations, gmapping which relies on odometry and lidar, cartographer is another one by Google etc..

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2018-08-16**:
Thanks @deb. So take gmapping. Can I make it begin with the old map stored on disk and have it build on that, or does it literally always start with nothing and then build a map which I can save? (p.s. if you have a link (other than reading the c++ code, which I could do) where I could learn more?

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-08-16**:
When you are navigating you have two options : you already know the map that you specify in roslaunch and it's fixed (and then you can use AMCL to localise the robot) or you don't know the map so you use one of the slam algorithms (and here AMCL is useless cause the slam already localise )

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-08-16**:
If you already have a map you don't use slam, if you don't have one you can create a map with SLAM (using a gazebo simulation or the real sensors )

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-08-16**:
You can go read the wiki about the Ros navigation stack about how you can navigate with the robot it should be a good start

**Comment by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on 2018-08-16**:
Thanks @delb. I did read all about the navigation stack but I am sure I don't understand it yet, which is why the questions. I will continue to dig into it.